# How to pause FFmpeg from C++ code?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, ffmpeg

I'm writing a VisualC++ program which have code invoke  ffmpeg.exe to convert video file.
I wonder is it possible to pause/resume ffmpeg converting thread from C++ code?

LR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is suspend and resume the ffmpeg child process itself.

The main problem is: there is no SuspendProcess API function. And there is no documented or safe way of doing this.

The only simple way of doing this is via SuspendThread/ResumeThread.

See [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/pausep.aspx) on codeproject about how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

There are no ways to controls the conversion using ffmpeg.

However, if you switch you mencoder, you will be able to do it.

Comment: “Switch you mencoder"? Do you mean use another tool instead of ffmpeg?Then, could you be more specific about it?

Answer (score 2):

This is an equivalent for Unix based command:

```
mike@krusty:~$ pidof ffmpeg
 22730
 mike@krusty:~$ sudo kill -STOP 22730
 [sudo] password for mike:
 mike@krusty:~$ sudo kill -CONT 22730
```

Comment: GREAT!  Tested, and it works!  As long as these two are followed:  #1) both input and output files remains unaltered during the "pause". #2) This 'pause' command has to be fired from a different terminal window, not the terminal of the ffmpeg process itself.

Answer (score 1):

No. This is a command-line tool, and once it is started, you cannot pause it.

Comment: I we use ffmpeg-lib like avcodec, could we pause it?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft API [::SuspendThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686345%28VS.85%29.aspx) function